# Expression for becoming homeless, which has the word 'street' in it? How about "pushed to the streets"?

Tags: phrase-requests, speech

If I lost all my money and became homeless, what standard expression would I use to describe this? The expression should include the word 'street'.

Would it sound perfectly okay to a native English speaker if I said "I was pushed to the streets"? Or what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: "lost real estate" has "street" in it: [lo]st re[al] e[s]t[ate]

Comment: If you wanted to take a lighthearted approach, you could say "living al fresco" or "sleeping under an open roof," but really there's nothing jolly about it. "Sleeping in doorways" and "camping on the streets" have a suitable air of physical discomfort and economic desperation to them.

Comment: Where I come from, if you expressed to me "I was pushed to the streets" then my initial thought would be that you joined a gang and started committing crimes in order to support your family. Homelessness is a possibility but not guaranteed when using that phrase.

Comment: Does the expression have to have "street"? There are many alternatives to "homeless" which means *[living on the streets](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/oct/13/homeless-nyc-people-you-meet)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like the phrase you're looking for is "kicked out on the street", which typically implies homelessness or unemployment.

Comment: Also _thrown out on the street_ (with a [Google Books example here](https://books.google.dk/books?id=0irfcNo6220C&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&source=bl&ots=amBC8dBAk9&sig=jrxrHPzCE-4hxHI174xD8XFj1zE&hl=da&sa=X&ei=_8o3VarDK6vMygPJmoGYBw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we (Brits) have a neat expression for that, we would have to say that NN became a homeless person, or a "rough sleeper".

"Pushed to the streets" has to be Indian English, right? AFAIK we don't have it, but I think it is nevertheless transparent to us. Just don't have the person "walking the streets" unless you honestly mean that (s)he is now a street prostitute.

Comment: A similar problematic term in U.S. English (in addition to "street walker") is "turned out," which I believe in pimp argot means "made to become a prostitute."

Comment: @SvenYargs: Ouch! Given that landlords turn tenants out when evicting them, this is really dangerous.

Comment: I think the term *they are on the street* is sometimes used in this context.

Comment: @SvenYargs Not much. Also, there's "The men will cheer and the boys will shout. The ladies they will all turn out."

Answer (score 1):

In U.S. English, a common phrase used to indicate homelessness would be "sleeping on the streets".

Comment: You're right, but I think the question is asking for a term that means "*becoming* homeless", not "*being* homeless".

Answer (score 0):

While *pushed to the streets* is grammatically correct and carries the meaning you want to convey, it's a little off idiomatically.

First, it would be *pushed onto the street*. I have a strong feeling that *street* should be singular. For example, you say *I live on the street* and not *streets*.

Here *forced* would work better than *pushed*. For example, "*He was forced to the street*."

The problem with *pushed* is that it has a connotation that the agent doing the pushing is a human being and the pushing is literal (i.e. physical). For example, "*He pushed me to the street*." describes a rough physical act and has nothing to do with being homeless.

Answer (score 0):

A *street urchin* is a synonym for a child who is homeless and living on the streets.